# I have a problem with sending mail : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, linux, synology

I want to make a python script on synology NAS. Script will sent a mail when backup done. I do not know why script whose was working on windows in pycharm do not work on synology... Its problem with context=context. Its Synology NAS with instaled python and python modules. Python see all file roads but he can't sent a mail

```
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "Backup zrobiony dnia: " + str(datetime.now())
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email

    # Create the plain-text and HTML version of your message
    text = """\
            Hi,
            How are you?"""

    def modification_date(filename):
        t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(t)

    html = """\
    <html lang="PL">
    <head>
    <style>table,td,th{border:2px solid black;}</style>
    </head>
      <body>
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Witam tu serwer Synology z firmy IdeaLogic</h1>
           <p style="text-align: center; color: #FF7B24; font-weight:bold">Backup został wykonany</p>
           <table style="text-align:center"> 
           <tr><th>Nr</th><th>Nazwa folderu</th><th>Data backupu</th><th>Czzas od ostatniego backupu</th></tr>
           <tr><td>1</td><td>VM_DEV_JIRA_NS</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/VM_DEV_JIRA_NS'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+(str(datetime.now() - modification_date(file)))+ """</td></tr>
           <tr><td>2</td><td>DB.OROOXLAB</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/DB.OROOXLAB'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/DB.OROOXLAB'))+ """</td></tr>
           <tr><td>3</td><td>WinOraDB</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/WinOraDB'))+"""</td><td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/WinOraDB'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>4</td><td>WV_DEV_REPO</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/WV_DEV_REPO'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/WV_DEV_REPO'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>5</td><td>VM_DEV_TOOLS</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/VM_DEV_TOOLS'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/VM_DEV_TOOLS'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>6</td><td>SSN_calculator</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/SSN_calculator'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/SSN_calculator'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>7</td><td>Firmeoo</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/Firmeoo'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/Firmeoo'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>8</td><td>ISO</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/ISO'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/ISO'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>9</td><td>AD-VPN</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/AD-VPN'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/AD-VPN'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>10</td><td>GitLab</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/GitLab'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/GitLab'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>11</td><td>VM_DEV_JENKIS</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/VM_DEV_JENKINS'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/VM_DEV_JENKINS'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>12</td><td>OLD</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/OLD'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/OLD'))+"""</td></tr>
           <tr><td>13</td><td>RedmineDebianOS</td><td>"""  +str(modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/RedmineDebianOS'))+"""</td>"""+"""<td>"""+str(datetime.now() - modification_date('/volume1/esxi_backup/RedmineDebianOS'))+"""</td></tr>
           </table>

      </body>
    </html>"""

    # Turn these into plain/html MIMEText objects
    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    # Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
    # The email client will try to render the last part first
    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)

    # Create secure connection with server and send email
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context)
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
    sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
        )
    czas = (os.stat(file)[-2])
    print('Wysłano maila')

liczba_petli = int(liczba_petli)
liczba_petli = liczba_petli + 1
continue
```

Comment: How is python unable to send the mail? mind sharing the full traceback (error) that you're getting?

Answer (score 6):

The `context` argument is new as of python 3.3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

You'd get this error if you're running the wrong version of python.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context)
```

According to the docs, the function has another signature:

```
class smtplib.SMTP_SSL([host[, port[, local_hostname[, keyfile[, certfile[, timeout]]]]]])
```

Your last argument (`context=context`) looks like a param definition with a default value. You cannot call a function like that. Just omit the context and call:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
```

This is the link to the official docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

Answer (score 0):

smtplib never takes a `context` argument.
Instead, you can initialize the context before calling smtplib.

Example:
context = ssl.create_default_context
# Optiional context modifiers
context.check_hostname = False  # Do not verifiy hostname
context.verify_mode = False  # Do not verify certiicate

```
# Create a standard SMTP instance without context
remote_server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server, self.smtp_port)

remote_server.set_debuglevel(True)
remote_server.ehlo(self.hostname)
remote_server.starttls()  # Context is inherited by having called ssl.create_default_context
remote_server.ehlo(self.hostname)
# Optional login
#remote_server.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
remote_server.sendmail(sender_mail, recipient_mails, text)
```

The same will work with SSL by replacing `SMTP` with `SMTP_SSL` and removing the `starttls()` call.

Btw, I wrote a nice library that does handle as this hassle for Python 2.7 up to Python 3.10 as I am writing these lines.
Also happens to deal with bulk mail, attachments and HTML mail.

Install with

```
pip install ofunctions.mailer
```

Usage:

```
from ofunctions.mailer import Mailer

m = Mailer(smtp_server='smtp.example.com', smtp_port=587, security='tls', debug=True)
m.send_email(sender_mail='me@example.com', recipient_mails='them@example.com', subject='Test', body='Somebody just told me...')
```