# Error with sending emails with python using smtplib, ssl and bottle.py

Tags: python, email, bottle

So im using https://realpython.com/python-send-email/#sending-a-plain-text-email

and im using this block of code

```html
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465  # For SSL
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"  # Enter your address
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"  # Enter receiver address
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

and i have changed some bits like the password and the mail for the things i need, how ever when i send the email i get this error

```html
File "main.py", line 32, in sendmail
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

when i try this code in a plain .py file it works but when i use itwith bottle.py it gives me that error, and i dont think its becasue of the other packages, any help would be gratly apreciated

Comment: Haves you tried using  just ```context``` instead of ```context=context```

Comment: if i do that i get this

https://imgur.com/MXN25U6

Comment: Sam's answer is correct. Use `context` instead of `context=context`. Your subsequent error is a new problem with your code, which you should put in a new question. (And when you do, please include the entire stack trace in that question.)

Comment: The right thing to do here is to not pass a `context` argument at all, because `SMTP_SSL` doesn't use a context until Python 3.3, and the question asker is using Python 2.7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone who i know did it for me today, idrk what he did but it worked, and when i did 'context' instead of 'context=context' it gave me another error, but its fine now

Answer (score 0):

@Sam H's comment is correct: use `context` as a positional param instead of passing it as a keyword param with `context=context`.

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context) as server:
```

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is to not pass `context` at all.  In Python < 3.3 the positional argument is accepted and assigned to the `SMTP_SSL` instance's `local_hostname` attribute (at least, this is what happened when I tested on Python2.7).  We can see the asker is using Python 2.7 from the image they left in the comments.

Comment: @snakecharmerb You're totally right. The context has to be created if used with TLS/SSL, but is "autiomagically passed" to smtplib, which does never expect a context argument. See my answer for details.

Comment: Other answer is in the link above for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697813/i-have-a-problem-with-sending-mail-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-key